# Updating User Profile Page - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm writing code to update user profile page for these variables.

- Update Username
- Update E-mail
- Update Password

For some reason I can't make it work, can I have some help with this?

Update: Okay so I got the code to work, but having another problem now - when trying to log-in with the new changed information aka login and password, I get an error that the password I am entering is wrong, I've included my Login.inc.php file for you to look at!

Update.php file

```
<?php
    require "header.php";
?>

<main>
    <div class="wrapper-main">
        <section class="section-default">
           <h1>Update Profile</h1>
           <form class="form-signup" action="includes/update.inc.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="u-id" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="text" name="u-mail" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="password" name="u-pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <button type="submit" name="update-submit">Update</button>
           </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    </main>

<?php
    require "footer.php";
?>
```

Update.inc.php file

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['update-submit'])) {
        require 'dbh.inc.php';

        $u_username = $_POST['u-id'];
        $u_email = $_POST['u-mail'];
        $u_password = $_POST['u-pwd'];

        $update = "UPDATE users SET uidUsers='$u_username', emailUsers='$u_email', pwdUsers='$u_password' WHERE idUsers='$u_username'";
        $run = mysqli_query($conn, $update);

        if($run) {

            echo "<script>Alert('Your profile has been updated!')</script>";
            echo "<script>windows.open('index.php','_SELF')</script>";
        }
    }


    ?>
```

Login.inc.php file

```
if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {

    require 'dbh.inc.php';

    $mailuid = $_POST['mailuid'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];

    if (empty($mailuid) || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uidUsers=? OR emailUsers=?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        }
        else {

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $mailuid, $mailuid);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['pwdUsers']);
                if ($pwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                    exit();
                }
                else if ($pwdCheck == true) {
                    session_start();
                    $_SESSION['userId'] = $row['idUsers'];
                    $_SESSION['userUid'] = $row['uidUsers'];

                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=success");
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
                    exit();
                }
            }
            else {
                header("Location: ../index.php?error=nouser");
                exit();
            }

        }
    }

}
else {
    header("Location: ../index.php");
    exit();
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: `$'$u_password'`?

Comment: You want to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: @stickybit This is just a school project, not going online :)

Comment: @u_mulder I fixed it, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Any error messages? Or records just don't appear in DB?

Comment: Also, would be great to see SQL that creates `users` table to check column names etc.

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Please see the help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
Best wishes on your endeavors! Cheers!

Comment: Just because it's a school project doesn't mean you shouldn't learn how to write your queries in the correct, secure way, and get into the habit of doing so. It's not actually much (if any) more difficult. Then if you ever write any code which goes into the wild (either professionally or otherwise) you'll already know what you're doing

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay! So your problem is right here

```
$update = "UPDATE users SET uidUsers='$u_username', emailUsers='$u_email', pwdUsers='$u_password' WHERE idUsers='$u_username'";
```

Let's say my inital database is like this:

```
idusers    uidUsers    emailUsers    pwdUsers
   1         xyz       xyz@mail.com    1234
```

So, if I want any change in the above I'll do

```
$update = "UPDATE users SET uidUsers='abc', emailUsers='abc@gmailcom', pwdUsers='121212' WHERE idUsers='1'";
```

or in generic way

```
$update = "UPDATE users SET uidUsers='$u_username', emailUsers='$u_email', pwdUsers='$u_password' WHERE idUsers='$id'";
```

what you are doing wrong is

```
$update = "UPDATE users SET uidUsers='abc', emailUsers='abc@gmail.com', pwdUsers='121212' WHERE idUsers='abc'";
```

this is not working because you do not have a idUsers as abc!
you need to get the current_session idUsers
Let say that id is saved in "id"
So your corresponding SQL query will be:

```
$update = "UPDATE users SET uidUsers='$u_username', emailUsers='$u_email', pwdUsers='$u_password' WHERE idUsers='$id'";
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195542/discussion-on-answer-by-rahul-agarwal-updating-user-profile-page-php).